# Ubuntu / MySQL - How to choose from the various downloads?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.  I would like install MySQL 5.5.29.

So I go to the MySQL 5.5 archive page 
http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-5.5&o=other
and scroll down to section **5.5.29**

Here I see the following options:

[image]

There appear to be duplicates here, so I hover the mouse over the links.

```
mysql-5.5.29-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz
mysql-5.5.29-linux2.6-i686.tar.gz
mysql-5.5.29-debian6.0-x86_64.deb
mysql-5.5.29-debian6.0-i686.deb
mysql-5.5.29.tar.gz
mysql-5.5.29.zip
```

My operating system, Ubuntu 12.04.2, is 64 bit, so that rules out #2 and #4.  I assume the .zip is for Windows, so that rules out #6.

That leaves #1, #3 & #5.

Please explain how I choose from these remaining options?
Perhaps Ubuntu is considered similar to Debian so thats what I should choose?
Or should I select the generic download?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have some advice for you.

Given https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html,

> As of Ubuntu 12.04, MySQL 5.5 is installed by default

Go with the 5.5.x version they supply, and update accordingly.

If you don't want to do that and really want 5.5.29 for a specific reason, go for `mysql-5.5.29-debian6.0-x86_64.deb` as Ubuntu was derived from Debian.

You may have to remove the version of MySQL that came with your ubuntu installation.

Comment: What is the difference between 
mysql-5.5.29-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz and
mysql-5.5.29.tar.gz ?

Comment: That's a plain binary distribution that you have to uncompress and install yourself. If you don't know what I mean, you're best staying away. Is there a reason you need the specific build version 5.5.29 rather than the one that comes pre-installed? Again, if you don't know then you probably don't need it

Comment: +1 for a very useful link.  As a DBA, I trust the package manager for everything *but* MySQL, because I want to be the *only* one deciding whether there will be any monkeying about with the files associated with my MySQL instances (so my choice, for me, would be #1) but you're spot-on with your advice in this case... `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` -- it doesn't get much more straightforward than this.